# Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch in MATLAB with cell

Tags: matlab, variable-assignment, dimension, mismatch

I'm tryting to store the text data into MATLAB 
but it has an error.

The data has 11 attributes and the last attributes represent the class of the data.

```
filepath = '/train.txt';
fileID = fopen(filepath);
C = textscan(fileID,'%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s','Delimiter',',');
fclose(fileID);

N = size(C{1},1);

D = 11; %number of attributes
data = zeros(N,D);
label = zeros(N,1);


for n=1:N %1~214
    for d=1:D %1~11
        data(n,d) = C{d}{n};
    end
    label(n) = C{D}{n};
end
```

I get the error:

> Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.
>   Error in readdata (line 19)
>               data(n,d) = C{d}{n};

Answer (score 0):

Probaly because C{d}{n} does not contain a number or what you expect, I sugest you try debugging before the assingment to see if every C{}{} is a single number and also check if textscan is properly reading the file with the format

Comment: You didn't really provide an answer, this is rather a comment.